# Return values of array from index to n?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I just want to make a method which would return the values of the array starting from index going till index + n. For example - An index of 3 and n of 4 should return the values

```
//Array[3]
//Array[4]
//Array[5]
//Array[6]
//Array[7]

public int[] subSequence(int index, int n, int[] array) {
int[] valuelist = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = index; i <= n + index; i++)
    {
        if((index + n) <= array.length)
        valuelist[i] = array[i];
    }
   return valuelist;

}
```

I am sorry for posting such dumb question but I am new to this and couldn't find a similar question.

My problem : I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` for what I am doing and I don't really have an idea about how this can be solved.

Comment: what is a1, a2 in your loop?

Comment: What is `a1` and `a2`? I don't see them anywhere in your code. But if you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, it means exactly what it looks like it means; at some point `i` is either negative or `>= valuelist.length` or `>= array.length`; so work through it in your head and look for chances for this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you,

```
   for(int i = n; i <=( n + index); i++)
    {

         if( i >=array.length){//check length of array with index,n

          break;
         }
     else{
        valuelist[i] = array[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that `<=` is still the wrong test to be performing in that loop.

Comment: what if `index = 5` `n = 10` in an array of size 3. `idexOutOfBoundException` again~

Answer (score 0):

1. Google for `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.
2. Read the first link (the JavaDoc for the exception: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

> Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal
>   index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the
>   size of the array.

Comment: Yes. This is a rather unhelpful answer that was more appropriate for a comment on the question.

Comment: The OP hasn't demonstrated that they've done any research on the cause of the issue before posting.  Reading the explanation of what the exception is should provide sufficient information to solve the question without asking.

Comment: Yes, that may be correct; *and* this is a rather unhelpful answer that was more appropriate for a comment on the question. For examples of more constructive answers, see some of the other response here. :)

Comment: What, you mean like the accepted answer that was just the correct code with no explanation as to *what* the problem was?  That's even less helpful to the OP's learning process...

Comment: I am equally disappointed that that was the accepted answer. I had hoped it would have been improved, because it was a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
for(int i = index; i <= n + index; i++)
```

You probably mean:

```
for(int i = index; i < n + index; i++)
```

I'm assuming `index` is the start index and `n` is supposed to be the count. In your current implementation, with `<=`, consider the case:

```
int[] a = new int[50];
int[] b = subSequence(0, 50, a);
```

You would imagine that would work, but your loop would go as long as `i <= 0+50`, which means at some point `i==50`, which is beyond the end of the array (the last index in the array is 49).

Another side-issue you have is:

```
if((index + n) <= array.length)
    valuelist[i] = array[i];
```

This looks like you're attempting to keep the index in bounds. Examine that `if` statement a little more closely, because that is not what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

`if((index + n) <= array.length)` this line of code is the problem with the java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

The code says to execute the statements inside the if statement *if* `index + n` is less than **or equal to** the length of the array.  Now, when `index+n` is equal to the length of the array there will be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to set values for your arrays in this statement `valuelist[i] = array[i];`

To avoid the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException try this:

`if((index + n) < array.length)`

This code has the equals condition removed and will only execute if the expression `index + n` is less than the length of the array. :D

An important point to remember is that arrays begin at zero when accessed. The length attribute of array is not zero based though. So if the code tries to access an array element using the length attribute it will throw this runtime exception, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. This is  because the code tries to access an element one element passed the end of the array.

Example:

```
int [] x = {0, 1}; // x.length = 2 and 1 is at position 1 and 0 is at position 0
System.out.println(x[x.length]); //throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
System.out.println(x[0]); // prints the first element 0
```

Happy Coding.

Answer (score -3):

if you don't know the size of array better use arraylist or some other collection classes with fixed size. After that you convert it to array or use it as it is.